# How do I reconfigure WSO2 API Manager Publisher to show more APIs per page

Tags: wso2, publisher

When I install a new WSO2 API Manager, it comes with several demo APIs. When I browse then in the API Manager Publisher, it shows only 10 APIs per page. Is there a way to increase this number? I can't find any reference in de carbon.xml or api-manager.xml.

Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be configurable. You can set the items per page by modifying the publisher app. Follow the below steps.

1. Open up `$APIM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag`
2. Locate var itemsPerPage.
3. Change the default value 10 to a desired value.
4. Then, open up `$APIM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/listing/template.jag`
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3.